# Python for with multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

This script reads lines from a txt file is used as part of my external command:

```py
for every line in txt do
    os.system(comand)
```

**Is it possible to use multiprocess with this to improve speed?**

```py
    i=0
    x=[]
    for file in os.listdir(carpeta):
     if file.endswith('.json'):
        x.append(file)
        i+=1
    print('the total number of files: ' +str(i))
     
    archivo='./temp.txt'
    strm=open(archivo,encoding='UTF8')
    min=1
    for line in strm:
      if min > i:
        min=1
      origen=args.o+"/"+line.rstrip('\n')
      destino=re.sub("\/(?:.(?!\/))+$","",args.d+"/"+line.rstrip('\n'))
    
      comando=args.r+" copy \""+origen+"\" \""+destino+"\" --drive-service-account-file \""+carpeta+"\\"+str(min)+".json\" --size-only"
      os.system(comando)
      min+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `multiprocessing` to launch the os processes from a list of commands.

Something like this:

```
import multiprocessing, os, re
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

def getcmdlist():
    i=0
    x=[]
    for file in os.listdir(carpeta):
     if file.endswith('.json'):
        x.append(file)
        i+=1
    print('the total number of files: ' +str(i))
     
    archivo='./temp.txt'
    strm=open(archivo,encoding='UTF8')
    min=1
    cmdlist = []
    for line in strm:
        if min > i:
           min=1
        origen=args.o+"/"+line.rstrip('\n')
        destino=re.sub("\/(?:.(?!\/))+$","",args.d+"/"+line.rstrip('\n'))

        comando=args.r+" copy \""+origen+"\" \""+destino+"\" --drive-service-account-file \""+carpeta+"\\"+str(min)+".json\" --size-only"
        cmdlist.append(comando)
        min+=1
    return cmdlist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    cmdlist = getcmdlist()  # all commands
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(os.system, cmdlist)  # pass each command to os process
```

Comment: i get this error

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined

Comment: Add the import at the top of the script. Install the module if needed: https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/

Comment: it's work. Thanks a lot. can I put more processes? What is the limit as the os.system consumes few resources?

Comment: In theory, the process count has no limit. It just depends on how many processes you want running together and the power of your computer. If you don't specify a process count, your CPU count will be used.